# How to create a new page containing references title before actual references begin?

Tags: biblatex

I have very specific requirements that I need to satisfy for my thesis from my graduate school. Two problems I have is about references and I'm not able to find any answers. I'm using `biblatex` for managing my references:

```
%% bibliography
\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=ieee,maxcitenames=2,mincitenames=1]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

and print my references using `\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title={References}]`.

Currently, the references have the bolded title "References" and immediately follow with the citations. However, I want a separate page with the word "References" centered (both vertically and horizontally) and bolded. In the next page, I need to start the citations (i.e., the word "References" should NOT repeat as a title). How can I do this?

**EDIT** As per suggestions, I've removed the second question and restricted this to a single question.

Comment: Hi Shaun. Could you please provide a minimal working example?

Comment: I would split your questions in two separate questions and give them a more specific title.

Comment: Note that the best solution for question 1 will strongly depend on the document class you use. Question 2 can best be answered if we have an example that reproduces the issue that we can play with. Please split the question into two separate questions (see for example https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864) and seriously consider adding fully compilable example documents to each question (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
\defbibheading{partbibliography}[\refname]{%
    \part*{#1}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \markboth{#1}{#1}}
```

and print the bibliography with:

```
\printbibliography[heading=partbibliography]
```

Comment: If you say `\defbibheading{partbibliography}[\refname]` instead of `\defbibheading{partbibliography}[\bibname]`, the `title={References}` won't be needed any more.

Comment: It should be noted that the format of a `\part*` heading depends on the document class. It will probably do the desired thing for `book` and `report`, but for `article` the outcome is different.

Comment: Thanks that worked for the dissertation template I'm using.